# Script for repetitive command line execution

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line

I am needing to run hundreds of command-line arguments in series. Although, for every command that I execute I need to change a settings file (text file).

For example I need to run "./program --settingsFile=blah.txt", but each time I need to change a line of text in the settings file.

What programming language will allow me to:

- Read file containing the command I need to execute (.txt file)
- Change seperate settings text file
- Execute command and wait for command to finish
- Loop until list is
  complete

I do not have much knowledge in shell or python, from what I read these seem to be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want it to run a specific number of times, or infinitely?

Comment: Almost *any* programming language will let you do this.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You can make a cron job for bash file or for python file. If it is running infinitely, you can run a process in background, again, bash or python...

Comment: yes he is asking the best from both the above scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what your code is, but here is a general template.

```
import subprocess
import os

while True: # this will make it run infinitely
    subprocess.run('path/to/program/file --settingsFile=blah.txt')
    settingsfile = open('path/to/settings/file', 'w+')
    settingsfilecontents = settingsfile.read()
    newtext = settingsfilecontents.replace('oldtext','newtext')
    settingsfile.write(newtext)
    settingsfile.close()
```

If you do not want it running infinitely, just make a small revision.

```
import subprocess
import os
number = 100 #replace with times you want it to repeat
for i in range(number): # this will make it run number times
    subprocess.run('path/to/program/file --settingsFile=blah.txt')
    settingsfile = open('path/to/settings/file', 'w+')
    settingsfilecontents = settingsfile.read()
    newtext = settingsfilecontents.replace('oldtext','newtext')
    settingsfile.write(newtext)
    settingsfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python for the same.

I've written a sample for one of your problem steps you can use and continue on others.

```
#Reading a file from command line
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
print contents
```